Database integration with service now
I have different catlogue within service now request.Wish to validate the user input within  snow front end request before they submit the form.
In my scenario validation would be on comparing data with my database or validation of data with external sites.
I want to know if servicenow has got the feasibility to perform such validations at any organisation level.
If it has got the feasibility please help me with the relevant details.Thanks
